# Pip install from private Google Source Repo

Tags: pip, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-source-repos, kubeflow

How do you pip install from a private repo via Google Cloud Source repos?   Seems like something that should be possible.

```
!pip install gcloud source repos clone [REPOSITORY_NAME] --project=[PROJECT_NAME]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used Cloud Source Repositories (so I haven't tested this), but it seems like you would need to do one of two things:

1. *pip install* from the repo's URL, if it has a public URL. For example, something like the following:

```bash
!pip install https://source.developers.google.com/p/[PROJECT_ID]/r/[REPO_NAME]
```

2. *pip install* from a local clone of your repository. For example:

```bash
gcloud source repos clone [REPOSITORY_NAME] --project=[PROJECT_NAME] 
!pip install -e [PATH_TO_CLONED_REPO]
```